# finding probability for unknown person among multiple candidates

Tags: probability, statistics

There are 3 people A, B, C. A, B, and C each have a computer and one computer, D,  that they all share.

Over 10 days we see A use his computer 100 times, B use his computer 25 times, and C use his computer 55 times

We know that computer D is used 50 times. Out of 50, we have certainty on  8 of the usage events of D

```
D is used by A on two occasions
D is not used by B on one occasion 
D is used by C on three occasions
D is not used by C on two occasions
```

I want to get a distribution of the usage of D, i.e. D is used by A 35% of the time, D is used C 50% of the time and D is B used 15% of the time. How would this problem be set up, or is it not possible to be solved.

Comment: There appears to be at least one typo here ("B is not B one time"). Moreover, the framing of the question is confusing (at least to me), and in particular I can't make heads or tails or your "For example, D is known to be in the store, but so are A and B." (Why is D known to be in the store? How is this an example of seeing A,B,C together?) I'd suggest trying to rewrite the question more carefully.

Comment: @Y.Forman I tried to clear things up. Let me know if it makes sense now

Comment: Maybe examine the [Integer Partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)) for the $42$ unknown uses